# python multithreading terminating problems

Tags: python, multithreading, freeze, terminate, slowdown

Im trying to search a large amount of websites for pictures using multithreading. A list of required websites is taken as an input. The websites are put into a queue with workers getting the websites from the queue again (my first time using multithreading, so if there is any big mistake here already, feel free to tell me!). It works really well, but shortly before having worked on all entries, the script gets slow at a really fast rate and seems to freeze 1-4 entries before the last one. So when a list of 15000 websites is used, it stops at entry ~14998, with 20000 at 19998 and so on. Im not even sure which part of my code to post, so here is the basic structure:

```
concurrent = 600
q = Queue(concurrent * 2)

for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=work)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
try: 
    for code in usedIDs:
        q.put(code)
    q.join()

def work():
    while True:
        code = q.get()
        [...]
        q.task_done()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be that the workers occationally throw exceptions?

Comment: not really, also wouldn't that result in a similar time of freezing for each run?

Comment: Well, you will approximately fire off 600 requests in parallel at a time. When you get to the end, you are seeing the long tail of the last batch. The tail will thin out, so you will see a natural slowdown. You could set a max time and retry failed requests to avoid hitting these slow cases. Either you have 2 really really long requests per run (connect timeout perhaps) or they are throwing and you never call task_done for those. That's my guess.